# Better html structure for putting the header and sidebar in left side column

Tags: css, html, wordpress, data-structures

In this [site](http://www.codetocode-developments.com/personal/) I have a wordpress theme with this HTML structure:

```
<header>
    <nav> ... </nav>
</header>

<div class="post-content"> ... </div>

header {
float:left;
with:30%;
}

.post-content {
float:right;
with:30%;
}
```

And I want to add widgets to the left column.

My options are:

1)make header widgetable: widget will appears before content and this is bad for seo.

2)put the header and the sidebar in a wrapper: the same, widgets before content

My question is: is an html bad practices to put header inside other div? And put the header after content in the html? What is the best structure for doing it?

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with multiple headers on a page: http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/

Answer (score 0):

I think the pest solution for you is to place the header with position: absolute. For that you will need to have fixed height of header element.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>

    </header>

    <div class="sidebar">

    </div>

    <div class="post-content">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px; /* give your desired width */
    height: 200px; /*give your desired height */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.sidebar{
    width:30%;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 200px /* this is the header height */
}
.post-content{
    width:70%;
    float: right;

}
```

Of course, in HTML you can put post-content before sidebar and it will also work.

Comment: But, I can put post content before header?

Comment: Yes, regarding that the header is positioned with position: absolute, the header can be also included after the post-content.